# Track history for Task Object

Tags: history-tracking

I found that there are all the objects have got Object History tracking related list.
I would like to know that Is there any History tracking for Task Object?

Answer (score 2):

History Tracking for Task object is still an Idea. You need to implement custom apex solution for it.

Or you can vote for the idea here https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpqcAAC

It is there for 6 years.